# Windows computers refusing to connect to WPA2 Enterprise Network

Tags: windows, active-directory, peap

We have all our computers set up on a WPA2 Enterprise network authenticating with a PEAP Certificate. The certificate is valid until 2017, and the network is functioning correctly on all the Macs we have in the building.

The Windows computers are both XP and 7 machines, all in our Domain correctly, all work over Ethernet, all have dates and times correct, nothing out of the ordinary.

Suddenly since yesterday none of them will connect. The only error message is "Windows is unable to connect to the network".

I've done all sorts of changes, even setting up a brand new machine with the same settings as always.

Nothing works. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm purely hoping for a fresh set of eyes on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Event IDs and Logfiles?

Comment: Where would I find these?

Comment: I would start with the Windows Event Viewer. Also please give more details about your environment. Do you use RADIUS, if so, which one?